# div bx causing mysterious infinite loop in assembly x8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

A piece of my code in assembly x8086 is consistently entering an infinite loop inside the div call:

```
1. xor bx, bx
2. mov bx, 0002h
3. div bx
```

the infinite loop occurs in line 3 it just jumps into this code location:

[image: it jumps into cs:1061 then to 1065 then back to div bx and so on.]

it jumps into cs:1061 then to 1065 then back to div bx and so on.

how can I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Please make a [mcve].  There are many reasons why this could be the case, the most likely of which is your division overflowing (did you remember to zero out `dx` before dividing?).

Comment: @fuz yep that was it! i forgot to zero out dx. thanks for the help :D

Comment: If you divide by zero or the division result is larger than 0FFFFh, you'll get a division trap. This means that the CPU pushes 3 values on the stack and (in the case of real mode) jumps to the address stored at address 0:0. If the value stored at address 0:0 is 1060h, the CPU jumps to that address...

Comment: `div` is not a "call", its an instruction.

Comment: Did you mean to `xor dx,dx`?  Looks like a typo where you meant to do that before `mov bx, 2`.  Also, just use `shr ax,1` like a normal person.

Comment: @PeterCordes don't be rude please. You are right though I changed that to shr ax, 1. my initial thought was that I need to check the remainder in dx (to see if it was even or odd) but I can just check the carry flag.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a drop-in replacement; if you did need the remainder in a register other than FLAGS, you might want `mov dx, ax` / `and dx,1`.  Or `setc dl`.  Or add it somewhere with `adc`.  But never use `div` with a known power-of-2, it's very much slower than a shift.  I wasn't intending to be rude, just kind of jokingly point out that div wasn't a good way to do it.  But I messed up, and the way I phrased it did look kind of rude, sorry.

Comment: @PeterCordes no problem man :) thanks for all the help!